# Post array from ReactNative by Axios to Laravel Controller and use ForEach loop

Tags: javascript, laravel, react-native, laravel-5, axios

I am trying to post the whole state by using axios which contains single values and an array. However I can access the single values but getting error to get the array which i want to loop through. My codes are :

```
sendData() {    
    let api = 'myapi'
    var data = this.state

    axios.post(api, data).then((response) => {
        console.log('respp: ',response)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
    })
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function getData(Request $request) {
        $user_id = $request->user_id;
        $items = $request->items;
        foreach($items as $key => $item) {
            echo $item;
        }
    }
```

Giving the error: **Error: Request failed with status code 500**

I want to get the array and loop through it. Any help?

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Error: Request failed with status code 500

Comment: It's an internal server error and is ambiguous, can you check your logs and see the actual error behind status code 500?

Comment: [2019-08-02 15:51:26] local.ERROR: Array to string conversion {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Array to string conversion at E:\\bvendadmin\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\ProductController.php:29)

Comment: 1) Is the array you are sending multidimensional? 2) Is echo $item; on line no. 29, if yes use var_dump() instead of echo

Comment: thanks found the solution. i am adding the solution. checking log helped me to come up with solution.

Comment: Happy yo help!.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
foreach($items as $key => $item) {
  echo $item;
}
```

I needed to do following:

```
foreach($items as $key => $item) {
  echo $item['id'];
}
```